# Android layout weight imageview not visible

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a confusing problem about android layout. When i use only one imageview the image will not be visible, but if I use two imageview (one for dummy view) I can see the images. My problem exist in only HVGA resolution (320x480). I think its because my images resolution. Because when I only use number_one.png image (124x133px) its fine, but if I only use result.png(597x90) I need to use dummy view to see it. Here is the code

```html
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <!--<TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content" />-->





    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:gravity="center"
        >
       //if I use number_one.png(124x133) its fine
       //result.png is 597x90
         <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/result"
        />
    //dummy imageview (i dont need to use it if I use number_one.png
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/resultx"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/number_one"
        />




    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:gravity="center"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/number_one"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/number_one"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/number_two"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/number_two"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/number_three"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/number_three"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/add"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"


        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/number_four"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/number_four"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/number_five"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/number_five"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/number_six"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/number_six"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sub"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/sub"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/number_seven"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/number_seven"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/number_eight"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/number_eight"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/number_nine"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/number_nine"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mul"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/mul"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/clear"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/clear"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backspace"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/backspace"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/div"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/div"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/equal"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/equal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/clearx"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/clear"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backspacex"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/backspace"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/divx"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/div"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/equalx"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/equal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Edit:
Fixed just change the parent layout_height into fill_parent

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to define orientation on LinearLayout

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

Or horizontal..

Comment: if i put that i cant set my imageview layout_width to 0 because of the suspicious size

Comment: Do you get an error or anything? If so, please post it. LinearLayout should always have an orientation and there should be no limitations because of that.

Comment: I get an error in my imageview layout_width :Suspicious size this will make the view invisible

Comment: i give it 0dip because I am using layout_weight. I can see the images if the resolution of the image is 124x133, but if I use 597x90 resolution I need to use dummy image view of an image with 124x133 resolution.

Comment: Ah sorry, I now see where you're going. Have you tried different scaling types? Maybe the image is simply too large

Comment: hmm I change my parent layout_height into layout_height="fill_parent" and the problem is fixed. But I still dont understand why. If I change the resolution into 400x60 I still cant see the image.